# Automated testing with chai js

Tags: javascript, chai

I want to load a configuration file for tests.

One of the parameters is type.

So how can I replace the next line.

`expect(res.body).to.deep.equal(test.expect`)

with "to.deep.equal" string.

I tried :

```
let exp = expect(res.body);
test.type.split('.').forEach(t => exp = exp[t])
exp(test.expect)
```

But then i got:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.assert is not a function
  at assertEqual (node_modules\chai\lib\chai\core\assertions.js:1026:12)
```

**EDIT:**

I managed to do it in the following way:

```
let exp = expect(res.body);
test.type.split('.').slice(0,-1).forEach(t => exp = exp[t])
exp[_.last(test.type.split('.'))](test.expect)
```

I'd love to get an explanation for that. and if is exist another way for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're breaking the [thisValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) of the last member (`equal`), which it tries to access but is no longer bound to `deep` object.

(I'm really butchering the explanation).

You can do:

```
let exp = expect(res.body);
test.type.split('.').forEach(t => {
    exp = typeof exp[t] === 'function'
        ? exp[t].bind(exp)
        : exp[t];
});
exp(test.expect)
```

To further explain, this is why you're seeing the `TypeError: this.assert is not a function` - the `equal` call is trying to access `this.assert` of the `deep` object, but the `this` is no longer bound to it. By explicitly binding it via `.bind()` we can retain it.

That's also why your second code example works, because you're properly calling the `equal()` as a method of `deep`.